# Why does an "only printing" notation modify the parser

Tags: coq, notation

The [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html) says that

> If a given notation string occurs only in only printing rules, the parser is not modified at all.

So I would expect that when I add an "only printing" notation, the terms are parsed as if there was no notation.
However, when I do this

```
Inductive Bit := One | Zero.
Notation "1" := One (only printing).
```

The term `1` is now parsed as a `Bit`

```
Check 1. (* 1 : Bit *)
```

Why does this happen here and how can I add `1` as only a printing notation?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me (but I'm no expert on the subject). It might be a good idea to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Théo Winterhalter mentioned, this seems to be a bug in Coq 8.13.
According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/13664), it seems to be fixed in Coq <s>8.14</s> 8.15.

Comment: Actually, this is fixed only in 8.15 (see [this issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/15058)).